# How can one reduce Microsoft Outlook's background mobile data usage?

Tags: outlook

How can one reduce Microsoft Outlook's background mobile data usage?

For example, today I wrote only one email (text only), received 5 text-only emails, and open 5 conversations (also text only), yet it used 16 MB of background mobile data:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Microsoft's offical website for the full details: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outlook-data-hog/a88b5e3f-2982-4558-a190-1afa93044e1f

You can do a number of things to reduce background data usage:

1. Turn off mobile data when connected to Wifi.
   This may sound strange, but apparently Outlook sometimes still uses mobile data, even when connected to a stable Wifi network.
2. Turning off the "Sync" feature
3. If there is the feature, set a data limit on Outlook.
   This will prevent it from eating up your data when you arn't using it.